# Grid component not resizing inside a Popover component in react mui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui in react. I have a Popover component, which has a Grid component inside it. The size of the Grid component is dynamic, i.e. it's height can increase. The regular behavior of Popover is to make sure that it stays on the screen. But when I use a Grid component inside Popover , and when the height of the Grid increases, the Popover is overflowing and going below the screen.

```
return (
    <Popover
      open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      onClose={handleClose}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'left',
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left"
      }}
      aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
      >
       <div>
        <DemoGrid  />
      </div> 
      
</Popover>
  );

function DemoGrid(){

  const [list,setList] = useState(["hi"]);

  return <Grid container spacing={2} >
        <button onClick={()=>setList(prev=>[...prev,"hi"])}>add new</button>
    {list.map((i,j)=><Grid item xs={8} key={i+j}>
          <p>{`${j} ${i}`}</p>
        </Grid>)}
  </Grid>;
}
```

So the DemoGrid component, basically is the component which consists of a button, whose on click will add a new Grid item and thereby increase the height of the Grid component, now when the Grid items are too many, the Popover overflows below the screen as shown below.

[image: Popover overflowing and not staying on the screen]

What can I do so that the Popover stays on the screen. And why isn't the Popover retaining its properties when I use a display:flex (Grid component) inside it?